# Does jquery cancel itself out when not in order?

Tags: jquery

I have been learning jquery and have noticed when putting scripts in the header section of my website they will work great UNTIL I put another jquery script either before or after that first script (like they are canceling out one another) I don't have specific code because I have noticed this while learning it, hoping that my tutorial would get to it sometime but this hasn't happened yet. I will list an example of what I am talking about:

The example below wouldn't work...

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(this).doSomething();
   });

   $(function(){
      $(this).doSomethingElse();
   });


</script>
```

I then would delete the bottom function of the script and then reload the website and then the first script would finally start working again. Here is when i delete the bottom script:

```
 <script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(this).doSomething();
   });

   //bottom script deleted, one above works fine

 </script>
```

So, again I am new to Jquery and am wondering if jquery sort of cancels out if scripts aren't placed in order?

Comment: What is `$("this")`? You didn't put quotes around `this`, did you?

Comment: I believe `$("this")` will never select anything.

Comment: i said i don't have specific code... I used this as an example to show what I have been experiencing once in a while...

Answer (score 1):

there no such a thing as cancel each other ..
just know that your doing some thing wrong ..!
and to know that you should open the console (f12 in most cases) , and see if there is an error..

what you did wrong in here is that your using `this` as a selector , while it's not ..
here is an example that shows that every thing will run smooth if no errors are there...

http://jsfiddle.net/sD8FQ/

Comment: sorry.. should have been more clear on that one... I didn't post the exact code that happened and had a typo there. I was just trying to give a general example of what seems to happen... I just want to know is it okay to have a function after closing out a $(document).ready()

Comment: yeah sure you can .. they operate independent of each other